# Word for a page with definitions

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a title for one of the pages in my application. It only contains words with their definitions. So this word is not going to be a part of a sentence but used as a title of the page and button name.  Something like:

`(title that I'm looking for)`

`car - a road vehicle with an engine
plane - vehicle designed for air travel`

I was thinking of word `Reference` or `Definitions` but maybe there is something more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title you are looking for, I think,  is "glossary"

*Traditionally, a glossary appears at the end of a book and includes terms within that book that are either newly introduced, uncommon, or specialized.*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary

Answer (score 1):

How about **Clavis**?

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clavis) defines it as:

> a key or glossary serving as an aid to interpretation

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clavis)

> Clavis or Glossary, an alphabetical list of terms in a particular domain of knowledge with the definitions for those terms

Comment: Good to know but I will go with glossary. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You could also use 'Index' or 'Contents'.

Index: An alphabetical list of a collection by title or other category.

Contents: A list of chapters or sections given at the front of a book or periodical.

Comment: I was thinking about the index but I think it only contains words without definitions, doesn't it?

Comment: Reading your question again I can see that a 'glossary' as suggested by @owain is probably more appropriate.